# Using Delphi 2007 and Indy TIdHTTP v10 get x bytes of data from a stream

Tags: delphi, http, indy

I am trying to capture still images from various security cameras around our offices on a regular basis.  I use the following code to do so:

```
Var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  I: Integer;
Begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Try
    // Loop through however many channels the camera has (most have 1 but 180
    //  cams have 4).
    For I := 1 To FCamera.Channels Do
    Begin
      MS.Clear;
      Try
        // Use basic authentication only if a user name and password has been
        //  specified for access to the camera.
        FHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
        If (FCamera.UserName <> '') Or (FCamera.Password <> '') Then
        Begin
          FHTTP.Request.Username := FCamera.UserName;
          FHTTP.Request.Password := FCamera.Password;
          FHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
        End;
        FHTTP.Request.UserAgent := USERAGENT;
        // Get the image from the camera.
        FHTTP.Get(FCamera.BuildURL(I), MS);
```

This works fine for most of the cameras as they have URLs that you can go to to get a current still image.  I have a few cameras though that will only give you an MJPEG stream and therefore, the FHTTP.Get never finishes as the stream is basically infinite.  How could I do a HTTP GET and only get the first MB or so which I could then extract the first image from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your specific question:

> How could I do a HTTP GET and only get the first MB or so

*IF* the web server supports the [`Range`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35) request header, you can use the `TIdHTTP.Request.Range` property to specify the desired range of bytes to retrieve, eg:

```
FHTTP.Request.Range := 'bytes; 0-1048575';
FHTTP.Get(FCamera.BuildURL(I), MS);
```

Support for byte ranges is indicated by the presence of an [`Accept-Ranges: bytes`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.5) response header (see the `TIdHTTP.Response.AcceptRanges` property), such as on a `HEAD` request for the same resource that will be retrieved with a subsequent `GET` request.

However, if the web server does not support bytes ranges, and *IF* the web server is using a MIME-formatted [server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) to send the images, such as with the [`multipart/x-mixed-replace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Mixed-Replace) content type, then you can enable the `hoNoReadMultipartMIME` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property to tell `TIdHTTP.Get()` to exit when it reaches the beginning of the stream data, and then you can manually read from the `TIdHTTP.IOHanlder` directly and process the stream data as needed.  There is a blog post on Indy's website about that topic:

[New TIdHTTP hoNoReadMultipartMIME flag](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20140305.aspx)

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  The web-server is using multipart/x-mixed-replace content type and the code at the link you gave me worked great.